# How to fill a matrix with letters and numbers from a text file JAVA

Tags: java, matrix

So I am trying to fill a matrix with letters from a text file, but it will not work.
This is what I have:

```
public void fillMatrix(String mtrx[][])
{
    FileReader f1 = null;
    int c = 0;
    int r = 0;
    try {
        f1 = new FileReader("C://Users/Connor/Desktop/encryptionkey.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f1);
    for (int row =0; row<mtrx.length;row++)
    {
        for (int col =0; col<mtrx[row].length;col++)
        {
            String words = s1.next();
            matrix[row][col]=words;
        }
    }
}
```

My matrix is made at the top by:

```
String[][]matrix = new String[6][6];
```

The text file looks like this:

```
STUVWX
YZ0123
456789
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: _but it will not work_ How do you figure?

Comment: explain what you mean by "will not work". show the output you are getting and the output you expect. this will complete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loop to something like this:

```java
for (int row = 0; row < mtrx.length; row++)
{
    String words = s1.next();    // will scan each row of the file
    for (int col = 0; col < mtrx[row].length; col++)
    {
        char ch = words.charAt(col);    // will put each character into array
        mtrx[row][col] = String.valueOf(ch);
    }
}
```

Remember that the `.next()` method will scan the whole row of the file, eg. `"STUVWX"`. I'm assuming you just want to put one character in each place in the array rather than the whole row.

Comment: Thanks alot! I got it running again!